# Spring Data ClassCastException Proxy cannot be cast to - findById

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have an API developed on Java using Spring Boot and Spring Data. I'm having a ClassCastException error when I try to get one entity using the method findById(id) from JPARepository

The exception received is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83 cannot be cast to class package.repository.FAQRepository (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83 and package.repository.FAQRepository are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I received it when I try to call to JPARepository.findById(id) However I'm getting the same error on other places calling other spring-data-jpa methods like reposory.save(Entity).

```
FAQ faq = this.repository.findById(updateFAQ.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundEntityException("FAQ not found"));
```

FAQsRepoitory:

```
@Repository
public interface  FAQRepository extends GenericRepository<FAQ> {
    List<FAQ> findByOperative(Operative operative);
}
```

GenericRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface GenericRepository<Entity extends GenericPersistentEntity> extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
}
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "faqs")
@Getter
@Setter
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE faqs SET deleted_date=NOW() WHERE id=?")
public class FAQ extends GenericPersistentEntity {
    @Lob
    private String question;

    @Lob
    private String answer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "operative_id")
    private Operative operative;
}
```

Superclass entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Where(clause = "deleted_date is null")
public abstract class GenericPersistentEntity implements GenericPersistentInterface {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_update_date")
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column(name = "deleted_date")
    private Date deletedDate;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you inject `FAQRepository` into your project? Spring clearly creates a proxy for a different interface.

Comment: I have an @Autowired annotation in my GenericService (Superclass of FAQService) with a GenericType variable specified by FAQService concrete class